# What does the Comcast/Xfinity activation CD actually do?

Tags: internet, windows-activation, cable-modem

Just ordered Xfinity internet service, and requested a self-install. I'm wondering what the activation CD actually does, and if I actually needed to wait several days to get the CD. Does it do a modem provision?

I'm running Mac OS X. As far as I can tell, it didn't install anything (it's not like I had to install anything on my iPad or Android devices to get them working).

It's easy to be skeptical and think that it's just a waste of time to wait for the CD, so instead I'm curious if anyone knows **what steps the CD actually does** after you enter your information, to get the service running.

**I'm not looking for general descriptions**, I'm looking for specifics (e.g. "it changes settings "x, y, z", then does this other thing, and finally, your service is activated).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use the CD for fully-functioning internet.

I believe it only installs "tools" to make your browsing experience "better", most likely via a branded browser and other such junk.

Comment: Gotcha. Does that mean I could have just connected the stuff and been done? Do you know anyone who has done that?

Comment: According to [Comcast Customer Central](http://customer.comcast.com/Pages/FAQViewer.aspx?Guid=6e68e2cc-ae62-4c17-b0c9-e8bc30943c6f): "An installation CD is no longer required for the XFINITY Internet self-installation kit (SIK) and is NOT included."

Comment: Boy, I hope that's false, or out-of-date info, because I went through this process with them, and waited several days - and if I could have just turned it on (after specifically asking if I could do that), well, that's just silly.